# Removing white space in HTML header

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm a complete novice at this, and I've tried a number of different CSS codes to fix my problem but nothing seems to be working.
This is my website: [www.sprinklesandstreamers.com](http://www.sprinklesandstreamers.com)
I want to remove the white space above and below my logo image. I'm using a Wordpress theme. 
Do I need to change this in the CSS, or is this defined in some sort of function? I have searched the Wordpress forums and nothing that has been suggested works.
Can anyone help me? Thank you so much!!

Comment: Hello, Welcome to StackOverflow! Linking to a website demonstrating the issue is very frowned upon here. You should edit the question to include the code needed to demonstrate the issue, and walk us through the steps you've take to try to fix the problem. Then we'll be much more able to help!

Comment: Follow stackOverflow as explained above by user!

Comment: I'm so sorry! I'll try the solutions below and if I still need help I will post the code, and I will be sure to do so in the future as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the padding from your main

```
.sticky-top .main-banner {
    /* padding-top: 125px; */
    padding-bottom: 0;
}
```

make sure that this won't affect your other pages...

Answer (score 0):

You can add this CSS to remove the white space:

```
.sticky-top .main-banner {
    padding-top: 75px;
    padding-bottom: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

File: style.css
Line: 917
Class: main-banner

Remove the margin
Modify padding-top: at least 50px

You should be fine frome here

Answer (score 0):

This is a "hacky" way to solve your problem, but it will make sure that if your theme gets updated, this change still works. Just make sure to **not edit your theme's code** but to add this using a "custom CSS/styles" option in your theme or using a plugin.

```
.custom-logo {
  margin: -50px 0;
}

.main-banner {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just debugged your website and here is my answer - add following code to your theme custom CSS *(if it's available)*, otherwise add these rules at the very end of your main CSS file. Hope it will help you.

```
.sticky-top .main-banner {
  padding-top: 50px;
}

.site-branding a img.custom-logo {
  padding-bottom: 0;
}

.main-banner {
  background-size: cover;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}

#content {
  padding-top: 0;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
```

**Here is my result:**

[image]